# If Philae lander had bounced off the comet and become uncontrollable, could we still have seen some of the descent photos?

Tags: rosetta, comet, philae

In other words, are the photos transferred "live" to Rosetta or did they plan to transfer them after landing? (and would they have been lost had the landing failed)

(yes, I am aware that "nice photos" are less important for mission control than for regular public like me :))

**Clarification:**

I meant **hypothetical** failed landing, where Philae could not land and started drifting into space, or tipped over randomly. What would happen then?

- Assuming Philae can't be contacted, did Rosetta receive the descent photos before landing? (so they are safe and can be transmitted to Earth)
- Or maybe Philae can be contacted by Rosetta even if it does not maintain the correct attitude and can still transmit any data it records?

Comment: Looks like it's a moot point!

Comment: Kind of obsolete now that the lander succeeded. You may want to re-phrase the question.

Comment: Un-moot now -- there's some concern that the lander isn't stable on the surface at the moment.

Comment: I wonder what's the speed of information transfer from Philae, in bits per second. How fast can it send a typical b/w photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact that we don't know 100% the status of Philae right now, but we do have some descent photos, I'd say yes, it is possible, so long as contact can be maintained.

Comment: The current situation may or may not reflect the condition I meant in my question (see the clarification)... But yes, your answer could be correct!

Comment: It seems this simple answer was the best one - the lander did not behave exactly as planned, and yet the photos have been retrieved. I still don't know if Rosetta received any photos before landing, so they could be transmitted to us even if the lander disintegrated upon hitting the comet, but I can live without it :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are two specific things that we have to have to get pictures in this case:

1. **Communication:** PearsonArtPhoto already talked about this. If we can't receive information from the probe we can't get pictures.
2. **The instruments cannot have been damaged:** Take a look at [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Atterrisseur-Philae-15494442575_099c1ff083_o.png) of Philae:

[image]

(Note: instruments are described on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philae_(spacecraft)) page)

The equipment isn't in a precarious spot on the craft (given a landing at the right angle), but if it this at a bad angle, we could see some damage (hypothetically; at the moment, it seems we're good).

As per your edit:

It seems [we have some pictures](http://www.nbcnews.com/news/photo/look-out-below-lander-sends-image-descent-comet-n247266) from the descent. You can find more information about them [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2831125/Rosetta-mission-broken-thruster-computer-glitch-scupper-today-s-historic-landing-comet-67P.html) and [here](https://uk.news.yahoo.com/philae-comet-lander-separates-rosetta-091454913.html?.tsrc=yahoo). There's also a cheerful last sentence about the latest pictures [here](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Rosetta/Touchdown!_Rosetta_s_Philae_probe_lands_on_comet):

> The first images from the surface are being downlinked to Earth and should be available within a few hours of touchdown.